# Connect to VPN when `wicd` delivers the internet

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-12.04, networkmanager, wicd

`wicd` and `nmcli` [conflict](https://superuser.com/questions/556239/using-a-vpn-with-wicd), so how can I get onto a VPN if not through [`nmcli con up`?](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphow-to-connectdisconnect-vpn-from-the-command-line.html)

Comment: You can do it from the CLI, follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient#Manually_configuring_your_connection The cnfiguration and the commands are different depending on VPN: OpenVPN, PPTP, VPNC

Comment: Thanks @MariusMatutiae. Do you know where `nmcli` stores the configuration settings for `nmcli list`? I can't see passwords etc from the `nm-applet` gui because they're ••••••••••'ed out.

Comment: I have them under */etc/NetworkManager/system-connections*.  I am not sure this is the same as Ubuntu, though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `vpnc` since it is a Cisco network.